# This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source raised while appendBuffer

Tags: javascript, websocket, mime-types, mediastream

I try to stream a video through a websocket. I made at first muted video transfer e.g. client -> websocket -> clients. All working fine with that. But when I try to get a video with sound from socket, app raise an error:

`Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.`

I have suspicion that reason in mime type or in appending data to buffer but I got no success yet.

Client:

```
    videoBitsPerSecond: 400000,
    audioBitsPerSecond: 126000,
    mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'
  })
  data.start(1000)
  data.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
    ws.send(await e.data.arrayBuffer())
  }
}
import JSON from '../config.json' assert { type: "json" };

const button = document.getElementById("capture_screen")
const video = document.getElementById("video_preview")

const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${JSON.ip}:${JSON.port}`)
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer"

const mediaSource = new MediaSource()
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', setupOpen)

function createProvider(captureDisplay){
  if(!(!!captureDisplay) || !captureDisplay.active) return

  let data = new MediaRecorder(captureDisplay, {
    videoBitsPerSecond: 400000,

    mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'
  })
  data.start(1000)
  data.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
    ws.send(await e.data.arrayBuffer())
  }
}

async function captureScreen(displayMediaOptions){
  try {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
  }
}

async function handleCapture() {
  createProvider(await captureScreen({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }))
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => handleCapture())

function setupOpen(_){
  const media = this
  const sourceBuffer = media.addSourceBuffer('video/webm;codecs=vp8')
  sourceBuffer.mode = 'sequence'
  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(e.data) // Cause an error
  }
}
```

WebSocket:

```
import {WebSocketServer} from "ws";
import signale from "signale"
const logger = new signale.Signale({})

const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8000})
logger.success("WebSocket was successfully created.")

let clients = []

function heartbeat(){
    this.isAlive = true
}


wss.on("connection", (ws)=> {
    clients.push(ws)
    ws.isAlive = true
    logger.info(ws._socket.remoteAddress + " has connected to a server!")
    ws.on("message", (data)=> {
        clients.forEach((client)=> {
            logger.note(ws._socket.remoteAddress + " send a data to: " + client._socket.remoteAddress)
            client.send(data)
        })
    })
    ws.on('pong', heartbeat)
})

const interval = setInterval(function ping(){
    clients.forEach(client => {
        if(!client.isAlive){
            logger.info(client._socket.remoteAddress + " has disconnected.")
            clients = clients.filter(cl => cl !== client)
            return client.terminate()
        }
        client.isAlive = false;
        client.ping();
    })
}, 2000)
```

I tried different mime types to look if something changes. Nothing happened.
Also I tried to make a query of data in case if sourceBuffer is still updating. When I received a message from websocket I check if buffer is updating, if so, I push my data to a query which should be loaded later at "update" event. But sourceBuffer never shows that it's updating therefore "update" event never invoked.

Comment: am also having same issue, did you find a solution?